# How do researchers imagine vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, intuition

A vector space has a broad definition, covering even matrices, than that deals at earlier stages in academia. One can read the actual definition from [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Ebeachy/courses/240/06spring/vectorspace.html).

I generally feel comfortable in understanding theorems or explanations related to vector space either imaging them as algebraic tuples or **arrows in Euclidean space** or sometimes as combination of points and arrows in Euclidean space.

Among these three, the second and third are prevalent in literature.

Are there any other ways that researchers imagine the vector space inorder to understand concepts and theorems?

Comment: In research mathematics, linear algebra is used mostly as a fundamental tool, often in settings where there is no geometric visualization available. In those settings, it is used in the same way that basic algebra is, to do straightforward calculations. If we visualize it at all, then the abstract vector space is viewed as a space with an origin and the vectors as arrows starting at the origin. The only numbers are the scalars used to rescale a vector. It's worth nothing that many of the most important vector spaces are infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thinking of vectors as tuples or arrows or points and arrows... is rather limiting.  I generally do not bother imagining anything visual or specific about them beyond what is required by the definition... they are objects that I can add to one another and that I can "stretch" and "reverse" by multiplying by a scalar from the scalar field.  I have my few favorite examples of vector spaces ($\Bbb R^n$, $\ell_2$, $C(0,1)$, $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\Bbb R)$...) that I can look at for more inspiration, but if someone were to start talking about a vector space of colors I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Visualizing vectors as n-tuples or arrows is the usual STARTING place people learn about vector spaces.  If we are discussing finite dimensional vector spaces, these viewpoints are usually well enough to leave alone.

However,once one goes to infinite dimensions these viewpoints break down.  While in theory (Given the Axiom of Choice) every vector space has a Hamel Basis (A set of vectors that no finite non-trivial linear combination is the 0 vector and every vector in the space can be written as a finite linear combination of them),  in practice we don't even know how to find those bases for most spaces.  While in the nicest cases of infinite dimensional vector spaces known as Hilbert Spaces we do have something called a Hilbert basis that we can define vectors as an infinite sum (of which no more than countably many are non-zero), many times we don't have that structure either.

In general, I personally view vector spaces as just another kind of algebraic object that we sometimes do analysis with,  along the lines of groups, rings, and fields.